# How to increase watts out of 12 volts?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am making a project, a DIY so please co-operate. I don't know much about electronics. The overall project needs some electric combinations.

I have a rechargeable fan with built-in battery but I am not satisfied with the speed.

I will purchase a new fan - is the speed factor controlled with the volts or watts?

If watts control the speed factor then how I can combine a series of cells to make it 12 volt as well as more watts battery?

I want to build a battery that can provide high speed to the fan motor as well as long last for the whole night. What are the factors in long lasting?

Comment: I refuse to co-operate!

Answer (score 3):

Speed in controlled primarily by voltage, so increasing voltage will increase speed. Doubling the voltage would potentially double the speed.

However, for a fan, power (watts) is proportional to the **cube** of speed, so the watts you need increases fast. Double the speed and the current increases 4-fold, so the power increases 8fold. Something in the motor is probably going to burn out or melt pretty fast.

But even if it doesn't, the battery now has to supply 4* the current, all night.

So if the fan originally took 1 amp at 6V, it will now take 4 amps at 12V. And if you want it to last 12 hours, that means the battery capacity has to be 4 * 12 = 48 amp hours.

So that's OK, you can use a car battery, if the fan doesn't burn out.

Comment: Great Explanation really good - but in my case I want to use 12 volt cell connected in parallel will it increase the amp ? the reason of using cell is to provide them constant charging so if electric city goes out I can be able to use it with the charging but in car battery case I think it is not possible to constantly charge it.

Comment: Your comment is unclear. But you can probably find the answers you need at http://batteryuniversity.com/

Comment: If you double the voltage, you double the current, not quadruple it.  The power does go up by 4 times though.

Comment: @R Drast : a fan is not a resistor. Power is a cube of speed, hence of voltage.

Comment: reference : "law" no.3 on the first page, http://www.nyb.com/Catalog/Letters/EL-03.pdf

Comment: @user_1818839 You're assuming speed is directly proportional to voltage, which may not be true.

I just happen to have a fan, variable supply and ammeter sitting here, so let's see what happens in the real world.
At 6V the current was 125mA, at 12V the current was 285mA, that's 2.28 times, so a bit more than a doubling, but certainly not a quadrupling.

Comment: @GodJihyo Good experiment. Such a low power fan is probably a BLDC motor with internal motor controller. If so, yes that controller can interfere with the basic physics, e.g. to limit power or current.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage controls the speed of the fan. But you cannot use a higher voltage than the fan is designed for, only lower voltage.

If a fan is designed for 12 volts and you apply, for instance, 24 volts (two 12 volts cells in series) you will probably burn the fan. But you can slow down the speed of the fan by applying lower voltage (to a certain limit).

I have several 12 volts computer fans that I use 4 AA rechargeable batteries to circulate air in several rooms, without the noise that is generated when the fans run at 12 volts.

So, you should buy a fan that provides the air flow that you need at the voltage that you need. But, if the cells you are using do not have enough capacity to run the fan overnight, then you can add more cells (of the same voltage and capacity in mAh or Ah) in parallel (positive to positive and negative to negative).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use 12 volt cell connected in parallel will it increase the amp?

Maybe.

I'm assuming that your fan is a simple device consisting only of a motor and a switch and a battery—no fancy (expensive) electronic speed controls.

If that's the case, then as user_1818839 said, the speed of the fan will be proportional to the Voltage. But note! It's not the [*open-circuit voltage* of the battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-circuit_voltage) that matters. It's the voltage while the fan actually is running. That will be somewhat less than the battery's open circuit voltage because part of the battery voltage will be *dropped* by the battery's [*internal resistance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance).

Using two identical batteries in parallel effectively is like using a battery with half the internal resistance. Therefore less voltage will be dropped within the batteries, and more voltage will be available to the motor, and the motor will spin faster.

How much faster? I'm *guessing* not much, but real answer is complicated by details of the batteries, of the motor, and even of the impeller attached to to the motor that moves the air. Even if I personally had all that information, I'm not enough of an engineer to be able to predict how much the speed would change.

Answer (score -2):

It's the voltage that increases speed. To increase wattage You will have to align your 12 V batteries plus on plus, minus on minus, so you will have more amps. More amps means more power per hour which in turn means more Wattage, as long as you are not losing it in... f.i. thin wiring, heat, and many more possibilities. Your main course would be, building up amps and stop losing power. So more batteries in parallel sequenced and thicker (like in 4x as thick minimum) wiring. After that and if you are still not having enough, you have to use capacitors in series. They hold up power and release it in frequency cycles so you will have to make several sequences so they fire after each other. Good luck. If it's just to increase speed I'd say just give them more voltage. If not... go ahead with what I just said.

Comment: "*... you have to use capacitors in series. They hold up power and release it in frequency cycles so you will have to make several sequences so they fire after each other.*" What is this about?

Comment: Putting batteries in parallel increases the amperage available, but that doesn't change the amount of amps drawn by the load. If you have a fan that draws 1A from a 12V battery, it doesn't matter how many more 12V batteries you connect in parallel, the current will still be 1A, the parallel batteries would just be able to supply that current for a longer time. This is from Ohms Law, I=V/R
Putting a capacitor in series will stop it working altogether as a capacitor blocks DC current.